# What does the sign that looks like $\geq$ except with the bottom line being sloped mean?

Tags: notation

I'm referring to this symbol: $\geqslant$.

No symbol list I've come across mentions it. I saw it in the book *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* by Christopher M. Bishop.

Comment: It is precisely the same thing as ≥.

Comment: The difference is in the font.

Comment: @DaveClarke They are actually two different symbols, [≤ (Less-Than or Equal To)](http://unicode-table.com/en/2264/) and [⩽ (Less-Than or Slanted Equal To)](http://unicode-table.com/en/2A7D/).

Comment: @JukkaSuomela, thanks for the clarification.  I will edit this question back to the original.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example of the symbol's context can be found on p19 of [Bishop - Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~banmi/elte/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20and%20Machine%20Learning.pdf):

$\qquad\begin{align*}
  p(x) &\geqslant 0 \\
  \int p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= 1
\end{align*}$

The symbols $\geq$, $\geqslant$ and `>=`, all mean the same thing: *Greater than or equal to*.

The same applies to its converse: $\leq$, $\leqslant$ and `<=`, all mean: *Less than or equal to*.

Context for the latter symbol:

$\qquad\displaystyle f\left(\sum_{i=1}^M \lambda_i x_i\right) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^M \lambda_i f(x_i)$

The differences can be attributed to the character set available, and/or the particular font that is used. In this particular book, the author specifies, on page viii, than they have used $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Every reasonable mathematics font will have both; usage is a matter of personal, stylistic choice.

Comment: Certain hardware platforms may not though. The ASCII character set does not have these characters.

Comment: @Greenonline ASCII doesn't even have $\leq$.

Comment: Exactly, hence the composite `>=` and `<=` characters... :-)

Comment: @Greenonline If you (have to) use this outside source code, something is terribly wrong.

Comment: I quite agree. I was referring to coding.